# Minor/Major upgrade on wix through cmd

Tags: wix, windows-installer, upgrade

I'm just started to work with WIX, I read a lot of tutorials, and questions here in stackoverflow, and I still have a problem with the upgrade section.

When I install a new version by clicking on .msi file, it removes the old version and installs the new version.

BUT, when I'm trying to do the same thing through the cmd:

```
msiexec.exe /qn /l* logfile.txt /i MY_FILE.msi
```

it doesn't work good. Some of the configuration files corrupted, for example, in the first installation the user should enter name of server, on upgrade he doesn't need to do that. On upgrade through cmd the name of the server deleted. (this is one of problems)

the lines of upgrade

```
<Upgrade Id="GUID">
  <UpgradeVersion OnlyDetect="yes" Property="NEWER_VER_FOUND" IncludeMinimum="yes"
                        Minimum="$(var.ProductFileVersion)" />
  <UpgradeVersion Property="OLDER_VER_FOUND" IncludeMinimum="yes"
                        Minimum="1.0.0" IncludeMaximum="no" Maximum="$(var.ProductFileVersion)" />
</Upgrade>
```

Anybody has any idea how to solve this problem??

Another question: If I want that the upgrade will only exchange the new files with the old files instead of uninstall/re-install, what do I need to change??

Thanx

Answer (score 1):

This isn't really a problem with your Major Upgrade rules per say. It has more to do with the fact that properties aren't persisted across transactions.  Checkout:

[Remember Property Pattern](http://robmensching.com/blog/posts/2010/5/2/The-WiX-toolsets-Remember-Property-pattern)

Comment: Thanx, I'm trying to figure it out, how do I take a value from the initial installation? and where do I need to write this value in the property??

Comment: Your initial installation needs to store it somewhere like the registry. Your follow on installation then reads that in.  If your initial installation is already deployed, this could be a problem.  You might need to harvest it from some app setting file or something depending on the design of your app.

Comment: Ok, suppose I found the var that holds the value I need, where do I need to write it? What is the 'key' field in line 12? 
Thanx again.

Comment: There is no industry standard as to where to save the value.  Line 12 (key)  is up to you.

Comment: The problem is when i'm doing an installation with full ui, it recognizes that this is an upgrade and i push an "upgrade" button to continue. in silent installation, (also no ui, basic ui and reduce ui) it ignores the upgrade, it uninstalls the old version and installs the new version. there are many things that need to be saved from the old version. i just want to make the silent installation do the same upgrade it does in the full ui installation. do you have any idea??? Thank you very much again